# vim curly brace indent incorrectly

Tags: vim

I delete some config by mistake! I'm trying to fix it.

settings in vimrc：

```
filetype plugin indent on
set autoindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
"set cindent
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
```

file indent(not only .php)：

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    public function getName() {
        | <-- the cursor indent is correct
} <-- this brace indent not



    // I hope it like this:

    public function getName() {
        | <-- the cursor
    } 

    // or like this:

    public function getName() 
    {
        | <-- the cursor 
    } 
}
```

I've googled many times, but those tips didn't worked with me.
I haven't figure out why yet...

Comment: Can you add your workflow? I have no trouble here. Maybe you need `syntax on`

Comment: @Nobe4 this is my [whole vimrc](https://github.com/kaiyulee/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc)

Comment: Maybe it's related to your config/plugins: have a look at [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/1821)

Comment: @Nobe4 Maybe you're right, I also considered about the plugins effect, I'll try your link. Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome, next time come post your question directly [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Nobe4 I've found the plugin: `luochen1990/rainbow`, It has [issue](https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow/issues/20) opened too. I practise my English :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109827/discussion-between-kaiyu-lee-and-nobe4).

Answer (score 0):

The error was related to a plugin which has an [open issue](https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow/issues/20) : [luochen1990/rainbow/](https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow/)

As a general rule, for debugging vim, trying to remove all plugins/fancy configuration is a good idea.

It's also worth reading [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file/2004#2004) for more insight on how to debug your vimrc.

Comment: smart~~~ I'll close this when the issue fixed.